# Disable default behavior - ModelForm Select widget choices filled with referenced objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

I am using a form in Django that is based on a model. So it looks like this:

```
240 class EventDetailForm(NgFormValidationMixin, NgModelForm):
241   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):tha
242     super(EventDetailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
243     self.fields['gallery'].queryset = Gallery.objects.none()
244     
245   class Meta:
246     model = Event
247     fields = ('title', 'description', 'end_date', 'start_date', 'gallery', 'cover_photo')
248     widgets = {
249       'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={
250         'editable-detail': '',
251       }),
252       'description': forms.TextInput(attrs={
253         'class': 'panel-body',
254         'id': 'event-description-editable',
255         'editable-detail': '',
256       }),
257       'cover_photo': SelectWithDefaultOptions(attrs={
258         'class': 'chosen-select-no-single',
259         'id': 'select-cover-photo',
260         'data-placeholder': 'Select Cover Photo',
261         'style': 'width: 200px;',
262         'tabindex': '-1',
263       }),
264       'start_date': DateTimeWidget(attrs = {
265         'class': 'datetimepicker col-xs-6',
266         'id': 'event-start-date-editable',
267         'editable-detail': '',
268       }),
269       'end_date': DateTimeWidget(attrs = {
270         'class': 'datetimepicker col-xs-6',
271         'id': 'event-end-date-editable',
272         'editable-detail': '',
273       }),
274       'gallery': SelectWithDefaultOptions(attrs={
275         'class': 'chosen-select-no-single',
276         'id': 'select-galley',
277         'data-placeholder': 'Select Gallery',
278         'style': 'width: 200px;',
279         'gallery-select': '',
280         'tabindex': '-1',
281         'organisator-profile-specific': '',
282       }
283     }
```

So what happens is that my gallery and cover_photo select widgets get filled with all the existing objects of the two types ( because they are actually foreign keys to other models ).
 I want to prevent that, and as you see on line 243 I have tried to delete the current queryset ( tried with cleaning choices too resulting in the same ) which works pretty well. The problem is that as you see I use my custom select widget in which I set some default options. It looks like this:

```
 62 class SelectWithDefaultOptions(forms.Select):
 63   def __init__(self, attrs=None, choices=()):
 64     super(SelectWithDefaultOptions, self).__init__(attrs, choices)
 65 
 66     choices = ('', 'empty') + choices
 67     choices = ('None', 'no selection') + choices
```

The problem is that with the approach I mentioned above I delete those values.
So I said to myself "Well, I will get the needed values, erase all and put the preferred back". Tried it but it turned out that actually the objects that Django puts in are deleting the ones that have been set. ( adds the default ones after the init method has passed)
So I thought "Well, if I set choices=() in the initialisation of the widget (line 274), Django should not set any other values on top of that, because this will violate my choices" so I tried it, but it turned out that Django actually does not care about what choices I would like there to be and act the same.
Also tried to set the field's 'initial' property, still no results.

So, how do I prevent DJango default behviour of putting the referenced objects into the choices list of my select?

Thanks.

Comment: I am confused, gallery is a `ForeignKey` in your model. So what exactly you want it to happen with gallery field? You don't want to show it to user? or what custom choices you want to introduce?

Comment: @AamirAdnan I fill the custom choices later on with JavaScript. The purpose of the form is more about the testing if the data is correct after it is submitted.

Comment: Setting none queryset `self.fields['gallery'].queryset = Gallery.objects.none()` (as you are doing should work). What are `NgFormValidationMixin` and `NgModelForm` forms, can you post them? FYI: setting a none queryset and then passing in some value from frontend for gallery field will not validate the form as that will be considered as invalid choice because queryset is none.

Comment: You can check `NgFormValidationMixin` and `NgModelForm`  here https://github.com/jrief/django-angular . And yes, it works, but I have mentioned already why I cannot use this method aside from your statement. What happens is: 1.in `SelectWithDefaultOptions` the default values are set in the options.  
2. Django sets all values from queryset to the options, deleting the previous.  
3. Anything I do in the form.  
So the point is that the default values are being overwritten with no chance of rewinding at the point the control comes to the form.

Comment: Try this http://dpaste.com/3KRYY7S?

Comment: @AamirAdnan If you read the question more carefully, you'll notice that I have tried this already. As I Said, the default values are already lost at that point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75245/discussion-between-aamir-adnan-and-victor175).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed it, with a little help from @AamirAdnan:

```
 65 class SelectWithDefaultOptions(forms.Select):
 66   def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
 67     choices = ()
 68     choices += (('empty', ''),)
 69     choices += (('no selection', 'None'),)
 70     self.choices = choices
 71    
 72     if value is None:
 73         value = ''
 74    
 75     final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
 76     output = [format_html('<select{0}>', flatatt(final_attrs))]
 77     options = self.render_options((), [value])
 78     
 79     if options:
 80         output.append(options)
 81         output.append('</select>')
 82         
 83     return mark_safe('\n'.join(output))
```

Just improved the widget render function.

It is not exactly what was asked for, but it works. What happens is:
 1. Django sets the choices value to the referenced objects
 2. Before the widget is rendered, they are changed to the correct choices

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the `widget` defined in the `Meta` is causing this issue. If you just moved it to `__init__` it will work. First update your widget, The keyword `choices` in line `def __init__(self, attrs=None, choices=())` means that the choices by default is empty but any instance may override it passing in some values. So you need to set it empty tuple explicitly:

```
class SelectWithDefaultOptions(forms.Select):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None, choices=()):
        super(SelectWithDefaultOptions, self).__init__(attrs, choices)
        choices = () # explicitly setting choices to empty here
        choices += (('', 'empty'),)
        choices += (('None', 'no selection'),)
        self.choices = choices
```

Now update your form to assign widget to `gallery` field in `__init__` rather than in `Meta` class:

```
class EventDetailForm(NgFormValidationMixin, NgModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventDetailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['gallery'].widget = SelectWithDefaultOptions(attrs={
            'class': 'chosen-select-no-single',
            'id': 'select-galley',
            'data-placeholder': 'Select Gallery',
            'style': 'width: 200px;',
            'gallery-select': '',
            'tabindex': '-1',
            'organisator-profile-specific': '',
        }

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'end_date', 'start_date', 'gallery', 'cover_photo')
```

OR You don't need any custom widget at all. Just set the choices in forms `__init__` method and replace the `SelectWithDefaultOptions` widget name with `forms.Select` in `Meta` (This is cleaner and simpler):

```
class EventDetailForm(NgFormValidationMixin, NgModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventDetailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['gallery'].widget.choices = (('', 'Empty',),)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'end_date', 'start_date', 'gallery', 'cover_photo')
        widgets = {
            'gallery': forms.Select(attrs={
                'class': 'chosen-select-no-single',
                'id': 'select-galley',
                'data-placeholder': 'Select Gallery',
                'style': 'width: 200px;',
                'gallery-select': '',
                'tabindex': '-1',
                'organisator-profile-specific': '',
            }),
        }
```

Comment: It is actually prefered that you create your own widget, because as in my case, if you have a several fields that require such attention ( here - gallery and cover_photo ), you will have to set the options manually every time. This will result in code redundancy and is not quite in harmony with the DRY philosophy.